# How can "k in d" be False, but "k in d.keys()" be True?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have some python code that's throwing a KeyError exception.  So far I haven't been able to reproduce outside of the operating environment, so I can't post a reduced test case here.

The code that's raising the exception is iterating through a loop like this:

```
for k in d.keys():
    if condition:
        del d[k]
```

The `del[k]` line throws the exception.  I've added a `try/except` clause around it and have been able to determine that `k in d` is False, but `k in d.keys()` is True.

The keys of `d` are bound methods of old-style class instances.

The class implements `__cmp__` and `__hash__`, so that's where I've been focusing my attention.

Comment: Well, if you now what `k` is causing the problems, why don't you just see whether it exist in `d.keys()` and in `d`?

Comment: Let me clarify, if you ignore the iteration and just test the dictionary, there is a key for which `k in d` is true but `k in d.keys()` is false? I.e. the iteration is irrelevant to the issue?

Comment: Could you show your `__hash__` function as well?

Comment: @Charles: but he's not iterating over a dictionary!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`k in d.keys()` will test equality iteratively for each key, while `k in d` uses `__hash__`, so your `__hash__` may be broken (i.e. it returns different hashes for objects that compare equal).

Comment: `__hash__` is buildbot's buildbot.util.ComparableMixin.__hash__, which looks at an instance's compare_attrs to generate a hash value.  These values were changing over time, so the object's hash wasn't stable for its lifetime.

Comment: Yup, that's another way to break `__hash__`. But then it doesn't even make sense to use the object as a dictionary key.

Comment: Yeah, it's not my code that's putting the object as the dictionary key (un)fortunately.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. The problem is also that you cannot delete entries in a dict while iterating over it. This is a beginner mistake and should definitively be the first answer. The hash thing may also be correct. But that problem should not be illustrated with an example that is incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Simple example of what's broken, for interest:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> class BrokenHash(object):
...     def __hash__(self):
...             global count
...             count += 1
...             return count
...
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...             return True
...
>>> foo = BrokenHash()
>>> bar = BrokenHash()
>>> foo is bar
False
>>> foo == bar
True
>>> baz = {bar:1}
>>> foo in baz
False
>>> foo in baz.keys()
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't delete items in `d` while iterating over it, store the keys you want to delete in a list and delete them in another loop:

```
deleted = []
for k in d.keys():
    if condition:
        deleted.append(k)
for k in deleted:
    del d[k]
```

Comment: he's not iterating over `d`, he's iterating over `d.keys()` list

Comment: @SilentGhost if the keys are lazy loaded (which I suspect they are but cannot confirm at the moment) then it's effectively the same thing in this context.

Comment: @what do you mean lazy loaded? it's a list.

Comment: SilentGhost is completely right, `d.keys()` already gives a new list of items, so there is no point to copy it again and it won't make a difference.

Comment: @SilentGhost you're right, unless he is on python 3.x where dict.keys() returns an iterator. Also maybe he could be modifying `d` when testing `condition` ?

Comment: surely, old-style classes mentioned in a question and the python-2.x tag indicate that he is not on py3k. In py3k the sample code would raise a `RuntimeError`

Comment: This also doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Chris I suspect it's the hash function -- could you add that to your question above?

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing would throw a a concurrent modification exception in Java. `d.keys()` creates a list of the keys as they exist when you call it, but that list is now static - modifications to `d` will not change a stored version of `d.keys()`. So when you iterate over `d.keys()` but delete items, you end up with the possibility of modifying a key that is no longer there.

You can use `d.pop(k, None)`, which will return either the value mapped to `k` or `None`, if `k` is not present. This avoids the `KeyError` problem.

EDIT: For clarification, to prevent more phantom downmods (no problem with negative feedback, just make it constructive and leave a comment so we can have a potentially informative discussion - I'm here to learn as well as help):

**It's true that in this particular condition it shouldn't get messed up**. I was just bringing it up as a potential issue, because if he's using the same kind of coding scheme in another portion of the program where he **isn't** so careful/lucky about how he's treating the data structure, such problems could arise. He isn't even using a dictionary, as well, but rather a class that implements certain methods so you can treat it in a similar fashion.

Comment: No, that's not true -- if you only ever `del d[k]` for `k` in `d.keys()`, you'll never delete a key twice, since keys are unique.

Comment: Assuming everything is as he has it above, keys are unique in a dictionary, and he only deletes keys once per iteration so he's not deleting keys that he's already deleted.

Comment: Well yes, that's true that in this particular condition it shouldn't get messed up. I was just bringing it up as a potential issue. He isn't even using a dictionary, as well, but rather a class that implements certain methods.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, that's why I downvoted you. I hate when people give an obviously wrong answer, or are just guessing. If you don't know the answer, please don't throw guesses at the wall, it doesn't help.